# python regex retrieve only one group

Tags: python, regex

I have juste a little experience with the regex, and now I have a little problem.

I must retrieve the strings between the .

So here is a sample :

```
Categories: <a href="/car/2/page1.html">2</a>, <a href="/car/nissan/">nissan</a>,<a href="/car/all/page1.html">all</a>
```

And this is my little regex:

```
re.findall("""<a href=".*">.*</a>""",string)
```

Well, it works , but I just want the strings between the , not the href, 
so how could I do this ?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parentheses to form a capturing group:

```
'<a href=".*">(.*)</a>'
```

You also probably want to use a [non-greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) quantifier to avoid matching far more than you intended.

```
'<a href=".*?">(.*?)</a>'
```

Result:

```
['2', 'nissan', 'all']
```

Or even better, consider using an HTML parser, such as [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Comment: +1 to BeautifulSoup, you will not have to tackle utf-8 parsing and html-encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is never a good idea for parsing HTML. There are too many edge cases that make crafting a robust regular expression difficult. Consider the following perfectly browser-viewable links:

```
< a href="/car/all/page1.html">all</a>
<a  href="/car/all/page1.html">all</a>
<a href= "/car/all/page1.html">all</a>
<a id="foo" href="/car/all/page1.html">all</a>
<a
 href="/car/all/page1.html">all</a>
```

All of which will not be matched by the given regular expression. I highly recommend an HTML parser, such as Beautiful Soup or lxml. Here's an lxml example:

```
from lxml import etree

html = """
Categories: <a href="/car/2/page1.html">2</a>, <a href="/car/nissan/">nissan</a>,<a href="/car/all/page1.html">all</a>
"""
doc = etree.HTML(html)
result = doc.xpath('//a[@href]/text()')
```

Result:

```
['2', 'nissan', 'all']
```

no matter if the HTML is different or even somewhat malformed.

Comment: I've also seen `<a>` tags in the wild with only single quotes or even *no* quotes around the href value.